# FieldFrame Causing White Screen of Death

Tags: pixelandtonic

Running an EE 1.7.3 site that has FieldFrame installed. Everything works fine locally, but when I upload the site to GoDaddy's shared hosting (cPanel), the site goes WSoD. Tried updating to the latest available version of FieldFrame and haven't had any luck. Is there perhaps a server setting or something I'm missing?

Comment: I'd check the php version on the server. It's likely that the server is running a newer version of php that fieldframe doesn't run on considering the last time that fieldframe was actively developed. Is there any way that you can upgrade your site to 2.9?

Comment: I agree with CreateSean, older versions of EE and addons don't always play well with newer versions of PHP. I would suggest downgrading the PHP version temporarily if you can to get it working again, then upgrading to EE2.

Comment: PHP versions are similar: works on PHP5.3.24, doesn’t work on PHP5.3.28. I've tried making sure the same modules are activated between the two, but so far that hasn’t made a difference. Some of the modules are different versions themselves; don’t know if that may be the problem. I don’t think the client will be interested in upgrading to 2.9.